# Mahalanobis distances all equal for a low rank data matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, multivariate-normal-distribution

I have a $n \times d$ matrix $X$ containing $n < d$ realisations of a $d$-variate random vector. I compute Mahalanobis distances to assess multivariate normality of the random vector. Since the sample covariance matrix is singular, I use the Matlab function CorrelationMatrix [by D. Sun](http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/~matsundf/CorrelationMatrix.m) to compute the "nearest" positive definite correlation matrix as follows

```
corm = CorrelationMatrix(corr(X),ones(size(X,1),1),1.0e-5,1.0e-6).
```

Though Matlab is able to compute the inverse of $corm$, the $n$ diagonal entries of $(X-\bar{X}) {corm}^{-1} (X-\bar{X})'$ are all equal to each other, and all non-diagonal entries are also equal. If I exclude $d-n+1$ columns of $X$, distances become unequal. Does anybody know why? Many thanks!

Comment: Could you explain how computing Mahalanobis distances would provide any information at all about the multivariate normality?

Comment: @whuber Pls see [A. McNeil, R. Frey, P. Embrechts "Quantitative Risk Management" (2015) pp. 180-181](https://books.google.de/books?id=SfJnBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA181&lpg=PA181&dq=mcneil+quantitative+risk+management+mahalanobis+distance&source=bl&ots=luiJKMArnE&sig=dXXVQ9-6uJ2c2DM4YibgCODCKIc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLm93o2MbOAhXBBsAKHW_GB_8Q6AEINDAD#v=onepage&q=mcneil%20quantitative%20risk%20management%20mahalanobis%20distance&f=false). $(X-\mu){\Sigma}^{-1}(X-\mu)' \sim \chi^2_d$ for $X$ multivariate normal, so Mahal. distances should "behave roughly like an iid sample from a $\chi^2_d$ distribution".

Comment: But there's absolutely no way to determine that until you have many more observations than dimensions!

Comment: @whuber True - let's assume I compute Mahalanobis distances out of curiosity then ;)

Comment: You should replace the matlab function above with a Moore-Penrose generalized inverse